# SQL: How can I do a keyword search using words stored in a separate search table?

Tags: sql, sql-like, keyword-search

I am doing a keyword search in a `SQL` table where I want to search for a set of keywords `word1, word2, ... , wordn` and flag instances where these keywords are found in a new column.  Assuming that I am looking for these keywords in a variable `[Description]` in `#TABLE`, the query I am using looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  , (CASE WHEN [Description] LIKE '%word1%' THEN 'word1'
          WHEN [Description] LIKE '%word2%' THEN 'word2'
          ...
          WHEN [Description] LIKE '%wordn%' THEN 'wordn'
          END) as Keywords
INTO #RESULTS_TABLE
FROM #TABLE
```

Now, the problem with this method is that the keywords I am searching are hard-coded into the code, which makes it inconvenient if I want to alter the set of keywords that I am searching for.  Instead of doing this, I would like to have the keywords I will search in some separate table `#KEYWORDS` as a variable `[words]` and then reference all the keywords listed in that table (under that variable name) for the search.  This would allow me to alter the search table and then re-run the select query on the updated search table, without having to change the select code.

**Question:** Assuming I have a table `#KEYWORDS` populated with the keywords I want to search, what is the best way to write the keyword search query so that it gets the keywords from the table rather than from hardcoded terms?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you asked for (that's why I'm writing a comment instead of an answer), but I think you should avoid such a case when structure with lots of like conditions. They can become very slow with much data. Despide the fact, you can simply write "case description when..." instead of every time "case when description", it seems like you just need to create a substring and don't require a case when at all. Isn't it possible to just take the first five characters or a similar solution? This would be much faster and better to read.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be a temp table:

```
create temporary table words_table (
words varchar
);

insert into words_table values
(word1),
(word2), --  etc for the rest of your rows
```

Then you can:

```
select t.[Description]
from
  your_table t
  join words_table wt on
    ON t.[Description] LIKE CONCAT('%',wt.words,'%')
```

or

```
select t.[Description]
from
  your_table t
  join words_table wt
    ON t.[Description] LIKE '%' + wt.words +'%'
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to create a ```Keywords``` variable, as in the original code.